# How to remove title post description in post type column name from admin panel

Tags: wordpress, post, meta-tags

[image]

I want only to remove description from title how to do

Comment: are you used any plugin or custom code for create this custom post type?

Comment: @AnkurBhadania custom code

Comment: Pest you complete code so we can help you

Comment: I only want to hide description in title column  using filter /hooks

Comment: Please check below answers

Answer (score 1):

The hooks to create custom columns and their associated data for a custom post type are `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` and  [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) respectively, where `{$post_type}` is the name of the custom post type.

Here is example

Override your columns values using `manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column`

```
add_action( 'manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_cpost_column', 99, 2 );
function custom_cpost_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'new-title'//new-title=your column slug :
            echo get_the_title( $post_id  );
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad answer not fill requirement

Comment: Why ? Please explain me.

Comment: you change the slug of tile and it not display at first location

Comment: you can direct override the value using manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column

Comment: how are i change it positions

Comment: now no need to add new columns. only add above code to override columns value direct

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', function ( $post_excerpt, $post ){
            global $pagenow;

            $custom_post_type = 'my_custom_post_type';

            if($post->post_type == $custom_post_type && $pagenow == 'edit.php'){
                return '';
            }else{
                return $post_excerpt;
            }
        }, 10, 2 );
```

Replace 'my_custom_post_type' with your post type